# vbscript with bginfo using objfso

Tags: vbscript, environment-variables

May I ask how I can make the username as a variable `(ex. %userprofile%)`:

```
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\Samplefolder\sampletext.txt", 1)
```

I suppose it's because it's a string with the `" "`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: by the way.. when I try to change it to "%username%/appdate/..." it returns an error: "Error evaluating scripted field"

Comment: Please use code tags in your questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Shell` object to fetch the `userprofile`. Sample script would be

```
dim objShell, strPath, objFSO, objFile
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strPath = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")
strPath = objFSO.BuildPath(strPath, "AppData\Roaming\Samplefolder\sampletext.txt")

set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strPath,1)
```

Comment: Hi Pankaj, it's returning an error with wscript --                                      set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Comment: @Alex - Are you using ExcelVBA or VBScript (.vbs) file? Try `Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")`

Comment: it's vbscript :)..removing the wscript from CreateObject worked, thanks! However, there's a new error I'm getting -- Object required: " on this line strPath = objFSO.BuildPath(strPath, "AppData\Roaming\Samplefolder\sampletext.txt") , position 2

Comment: Have you initialize `objFSO`?

Comment: here it is:
dim  objFSO, objFile, strLine, objShell, strPath
  
  set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
  strPath = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%")
  strPath = objFSO.BuildPath(strPath, "Appdata\Roaming\Avaya\one-X Agent\2.5\Profiles\default\Settings.xml")
  
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strPath,1)
  
  For l = 1 to 11
   objFile.SkipLine
  Next
  
  objFile.Skip(38)
  strLine = objFile.Read(7)
  objFile.Close
  
  If InStr(strLine,"222abcd") Then
   strLine = "No Avaya Ext"
  End If
  
  echo strLine

Comment: Your code looks incorrect. You are expanding `username` and it would be something like Alex.XYZ. This is not the path of your user profile. Whenever you have doubt, troubleshoot it line by line using Msgbox to see if the values are correct or not.